# Amazon Product API retrieving all products

Tags: php, asp.net, codeigniter, amazon-web-services

I am trying to pull all products from Amazon Product API, but as far as I know, that's impossible to do unless they give you access to Bulk Data Feeds.

Am I correct?

Comment: Like... it can be for categories too.. like, ALL books or something..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out Amazon product advertising API only allows 2000 API calls per hour.

Each call returns 10 products, so every hour I can call 20,000 products.

I used product_search call to make calls for each category, page by page, retrieve 20,000 products per hour. Within few days, I accumulated over 1 million products.

Anybody who's interested in how this is done, msg me!

Comment: Hi, would you happen to have some example code? Could you please share  some? Trying to fetch list of amazon books... salih0vicX@gmail.com. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

last I checked, amazons web services limit the number of results you may retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon recently changed their affiliate policy regarding API access. They want you to have three affiliate link transactions within 180 days to be in good standing. They will need to conduct a review of your affiliate site. Until then, the API keys will only be good for generating product links.